# Can we simulate real time traffic on e-commerce application thru jmeter with users drop at each steps

Tags: jmeter

Eg : Let say we have following rest API steps in my flow:
1. Login
2. Addtocart
3. Increment item qty
4. Applying voucher in cart
5. Updating shipping address
6. Placing order.

Now in above flow, let say I want to start with 300 concurrent users and at every step I want 5-10% users drop like:
1. Login - 300 users will do
2. Addtocart - 270 users will do
3. Increment item quantity : 243 users will do 
.
.
.
And so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create multiple thread groups. For example:

```
Thread group 1- Login
   -Login Request
Thread group 2- Addtocart 
   -Addtocart Request
Thread group 3- item quantity
   -item quantity Request
```

Now you can set manually the number of threads for each thread group. Set it manually as 300,270 and 243 and corresponding ramp up time.
Only thing you need to be taken care is passing the cookie from login thread group to the other two thread group.
For this Add a beanshell postprocessor as a child of login request and add the following code

```
props.put("yourcookiename1","${COOKIE_yourcookiename1}");
props.put("yourcookiename2","${COOKIE_yourcookiename2}");
props.put("yourcookiename3","${COOKIE_yourcookiename3}");
```

Now add a Beanshell PostProcessor as a child of addtokart request and increment qualtity request and add the following code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("yourcookiename1",props.get("yourcookiename1"),"abc.com","/",false,0);
manager.add(cookie);
Cookie cookie1 = new Cookie("yourcookiename2",props.get("yourcookiename2"),"abc.com","/",false,0);
manager.add(cookie1);
Cookie cookie2 = new Cookie("yourcookiename3",props.get("yourcookiename3"),"abc.com","/",false,0);
manager.add(cookie2);
```

This will pass cookie to your 2nd and 3rd request which is under different thread groups.

Comment: Thanks .It worked but I have implemented in different way with beanshell assertion,setproperty way.